# Project Parameters as variable In Altium

Tags: altium

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make the Project parameters show up in my schematic template.

I have a variable string called =Title which I'd like to set in the project parameters, but it doesn't show up. I know I can set it up in Document parameters, but I want it to be in the project since its global to the entire project and not just the specific sheet.

Anyone quickly know how to set it up ?

**edit**

The question may not have been clear.

In my schematic template, I have a string whose value is "=Title" without the quotations.
I have gone to the Project Paramaters tab {Project-Project Options-Paramters} and have created a new paramter.

For the name property, I have called it **Title** and for the value I have called **Test123**.

What I expect to have happened was my special string to convert to Test123. It does not.
I have changed the Name property to =Title and .Title and it still does not change.

If I change the Document parameters, I am able to change my special string into Test123.

Hopefully that's a bit more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

You can't use any of Altium's stock/unchangeable Document parameters names in Project Parameters. So "Title" in Project Parameters will not supersede "Title" in Document Parameters.

Comment: Thank you! This is correct; it worked for me in AD v15.0.15.

Answer (score 3):

Altium describes the process of implementing Global Parameters here:  https://github.com/Altium-Designer-addons/scripts-libraries/wiki/AltiumPCBProjectTemplate

a.  Create the global parameter (>Project >ProjectOptions >Parameters).  Remember, try not to use standard altium parameters (e.g., CurrentTime, Date, Title).

b.  In the PCBDOC, the parameter is expressed when you PLACE the following TEXT:
 .ParameterName

c.  In the SCHDOC or SCHDOT, the parameter is expressed  when you PLACE the following TEXT:  =ParameterName

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project-->>Project option

Window will appear with tabs.

Click on Parameters.

Here you can Add your parameters.

Comment: Ya I've already done that. I guess I should have been a bit more clear. Let me update the question.

Comment: can you attach the picture of parameters that you are entering in the parameter column?

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution would be to evaluate the parameter at the project-level if its document-level value is not defined (empty). Unfortunately Altium does not do it.

The same can be achieved as follows:

1. In your template add a parameter with the name 'Title' and value '=Title'. Save the template.
2. Create a new schematic document based on this template. (If you are working with an existing document replace the old template with the new template. Due to a bug in Altium the new template's parameters will not be imported. You will do this by clicking Design>Update Template and choosing 'Update All Parameters' in the dialog.)
3. In your project options create parameter named Title with the value Test123 (you already did that).

Answer (score 0):

after you set up the schematic parameter, on the sheet add them by adding Text with the type. for example  =author